# Check if current user starts with a specific letter

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a if statement that checks if the user display name letter starts with a, b or c. The problem is, it doesn't only display those users, it displays all users, still. What is wrong with my if statement? Can I do something different?

```
<?php

    $args = array(
                'exclude' => array( 1 ),
                'order'      => 'ASC',
                );

                $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( $args ) ); ?>

                <?php if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
                            foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) { ?>

                <?php
                    $args = array(
                                'size' => 300,
                                );
                    $img_url = get_avatar_url($user->user_email, $args)
                ?>  


                <?php
                    $user_display_name = $user->display_name;
                    if ( strtolower($user_display_name[0]) == "a" || "b" || "c"  ) {
                ?>

                <a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $user->user_login . '.domain.com' . '"'; ?>">
                    <div class="user" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $img_url; ?>);">
                        <div class="user-avatar">
                            <img alt="<?php echo $user->display_name; ?>" class="avatar avatar-90 photo avatar-custom" height="90" src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-info">
                            <h3 class="user-title"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></h3>
                            <p class="user-url">
                                <a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $user->user_login . '.domain.com' . '">'; ?> <?php echo $user->user_login . '.domain.com'; ?></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <?php } ?>

                <?php } ?>
                <?php } else {
                        echo 'No users found.';
                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're messing `if` condition a bit.

```
<?php
     $user_display_name = $user->display_name;
     $initial = strtolower($user_display_name[0]);
     if ( $initial == "a" || $initial == "b" || $initial == "c"  ) {
     .... 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please learn php syntax. Such conditions will always evaluate to true:

```
if ( strtolower($user_display_name[0]) == "a" || "b" || "c"  ) {
```

What you need is at least:

```
if ( strtolower($user_display_name[0]) == "a" 
    || strtolower($user_display_name[0]) == "b" 
    || strtolower($user_display_name[0]) == "c"  ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned Mubin, your if syntax is wrong. You could also use regular expressions to check if username starts with a||b||c

Here's how you can do it:

```
if(preg_match('/^(a|A|b|B|c|C)/',$user->display_name))
```

preg_match will return true if match for the specified pattern is found. The regular expression given will match any string that begins with a, b or c.